# Modal not appearing on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using material-ui and rendering a modal with redux when user clicks on a product, and it works great. Now I'm trying to add routing with react-router v6.

**App.jsx**

```
export default function App() {
return (
        <>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/:productType" element={<FoodDrink />} />
                    <Route path="/:productType/:category" element={<ResultsList />}>
                        <Route path=":brandproduct" />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </AppBar>
            <ProductModal />
        </>
);
}
```

The `<FoodDrink />` and `<ResultsList />` components render great and navigate as they should.

When I click on a result, it opens the modal with redux.

**ResultsList.jsx**

```
function handleResultClick() {
    onToggleProductModal();
}
```

The link to the product modal from the result card generates the correct URL.

**Result.jsx**

```
<>
        <Card
            component={Link}
            to={`${toKebabCase(props.brand)}-${toKebabCase(props.name)}`}
            onClick={props.clicked} // this calls handleResultClick in the parent, ResultsList.jsx
        >
            {cardContent}
        </Card>
        <Outlet />
    </>
```

When the modal closes the URL goes back to the category on the ResultsList as it should. (I know navigate(-1) might not be the best way, but I think its okay for now).

**ProductModal.jsx**

```
const onCloseModal = () => {
    props.onToggleProductModal();
    navigate(-1);
};
```

The problem is that manually navigating to the same URL does not open the modal, and refreshing the page with the modal open loads the page without the modal open, but with the correct URL.

Anyone know what I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are opening the modal thanks to the function called by the onClick prop. When you refresh the page that function is not called.

This is what I would do:

<strike>Remove `<Route path=":brandproduct" />` and modify route:
`<Route path="/:productType/:category/:brandproduct?" element={<ResultsList />}>`</strike>

On ResultsList:

```
    const ResultList = () =>{    
    const { brandproduct } = useParams(); //https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams
        useEffect(()=>{
        if(brandproduct){
        onToggleProductModal() 
        }
        },[brandproduct]) //every time brandproduct changes, useEffect will call this function
    // Rest of ResultList
```

You can then remove onClick prop from the Card component as the modal will open every time you navigate to `/:productType/:category/:brandproduct`, included when you refresh the page

Comment: thanks! this worked, when i removed the question mark from `path="/:productType/:category/:brandproduct?"`. was that there for a reason or was that a typo?

Comment: Sorry my bad, the question mark is used in react-router < v6 to indicate an optional parameter. No need to do that in v6.